# Custom font is not being loaded?

Tags: iphone, ios5

Hello I'm trying this [tutorial](http://blog.beefyapps.com/2010/06/custom-fonts-in-ios-4/).
This my piece of code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Bangla MN" size: 12];
    NSLog(@"%@",font);
    [mTextField setFont: font];
    [mTextField setFont:font];
}
```

It's giving null in log.
Here is [sample project](http://www.4shared.com/zip/4Hnf2nRm/TestApp.html) that I'm developing

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint? Checked the value of "font"? Case of your font filename, space in the font filename. Give us a clue as to what you have tried to do...

Comment: support of TTC starting with Mac OS 8.5.

Comment: i tried every possible combination and i have uploaded the test project also... please do look if you have time

Comment: @user1186899 it was for testing I tried with other file too which is ttf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already included it into project and correctly added into .plist, then make sure, that you use correct font name. You have to know, that sometime font name is not equal to font's filename

UPD:
**Solution were found.** You just forgot to include your font file in TestApp target membership. After including - everything works fine.

Comment: yeah I know this... and I installed this font and checked its name and tried that too. Have you tried the test project

Comment: @InderKumarRathore, yes I did. You just forgot to include your font file in TestApp target membership. After including - everything works fine. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: no i dont... just give the detail till then I will search what you said

Comment: @Nearby thank buddy... was missing this thing... :) thanks and +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

below is the code for the displaying the custom font Displaying

```
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 240, 40)];
[label1 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Grinched" size:24]];
[label1 setText:@"Grinched Font"];
[[self view] addSubview:label1];

UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 240, 40)];
[label2 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Energon" size:18]];
[label2 setText:@"Energon Font"];
[[self view] addSubview:label2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Before do any stuff, check for this!

1] Check the name of the font you given.

2] Type exactly as "file name of font".

3] Check if that font is exist in your XCode IDE. To Check click on your label > properties > Text Font > Custom > Check your font into list!

Hope this helpful! All the best!

Comment: 1 & 2 are correct and for 3 if it exits in xcode then why would I have to import it. anyways thanks for the tip but all of them is right